# Union of two iterators

Tags: python

Consider the iterators `count(3,3)` and `count(5,5)`. How can I create a iterator that outputs only the numbers that occur in either `count(3,3)` and `count(5,5)`?

Comment: in the concrete case that you mention, the iterator is `count(15, 15)`. In the general case, you're going to need stronger conditions on the iterators. Are they both monotonic? Are their results small enough to turn into sets? etc. How sparse are you expecting the intersection to be? I can't think of a good general way to do this.

Comment: Well then how do you want the union to occur. `chain(count(3, 3), count(5, 5))` does what you want but it'll be a hippie minute or two before you ever see 5 come out of it.

Comment: In ascending order, of course.

Comment: @alphomega Are the two input iterators guaranateed to be sorted in ascending order?

Comment: yes. I'm working specifically with count(3,3) and count(5,5).

Comment: cool, i just used that with an "or" instead of an "and", and it's good.

Comment: `(x for x in count(3) if not x%3 or not x%5)`. Deleted my earlier comment because I thought there was a larger mistake. There wasn't.

Comment: Regarding coding style, I find it more readable to test for x%3==0. Is there a performance disadvantage doing that than using your negation?

Comment: It's just a habit of mine to not test against 0. But yes, there is a small performance gain by using negation: 1.) no need to load a constant, no need to evaluate a boolean comparison. In both cases you end up jumping based on the top value of the stack, `not x%3` puts it there directly.

Comment: Your title says union but the end of your question is a bit ambiguous.  Saying OR instead of AND is more accurate for union; "... in either [A] _OR_ [B]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer to this question, OP accepted `(x for x in count(3) if not x%3 or not x%5)` as a solution in the comments. What follows below should work for the general case so long as duplicates are acceptable. If duplicates aren't acceptable, it could be wrapped in a function that stored its output in a set for further reference but now we're making assumptions on the total size that it will end up being.

---

one way would just be to interleave the two. This assumes that they both have the same cardnality. This will also create duplicates as pointed out in the comments.

```
import itertools

def union(it1, it2):
    return (item for pair in itertools.izip(it1, it2) for item in pair)
```

If they have different cardnalities, then you'll end up truncating one of the two. Here's a more general solution

```
import itertools

def union(it1, it2):
    it1, it2 = iter(it1), iter(it2)
    for item in (item for pair in itertools.izip(it1, it2) for item in pair):
        yield item
    for it in (it1, it2):
        for item in it:
            yield item
```

Comment: This will work when both input iterator produces a element during the same iteration.

Comment: Sorry. I was looking at intersection of two sets which is more difficult. Question changed! Union is definitely achievable this way. +1

Comment: wrt the first technique, how would you ensure there are no duplicates? (15 occurs a couple times, for example.)